# Web Audio Api - Fail to set 'buffer' property

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I got the following code for loading and then playing a `.wav`file on a `Chrome` browser:

```
   var songBuffer = null;
   // Fix up prefixing
   window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
   var context = new AudioContext();

   function loadSound(url) {
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open('GET', url, true);
       request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

       // Decode asynchronously
       request.onload = function() {
          context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
             songBuffer = buffer;
        });
      }
      request.send();
     }

   // Fix up prefixing
   window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
   var context = new AudioContext();

   function playSound(buffer) {
     var source = context.createBufferSource(); 
     // creates a sound source
     source.buffer = buffer;                
     // tell the source which sound to play
     source.connect(context.destination);       
     // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)
     source.start(0);                           
     // play the source now                                          
    }
```

loading is being triggered by:
         `<button onclick="loadSound('audio/sound.wav')">load    sound</button>` and the file loads fine when I generate the event.

and playing handled by : `<button onclick="playSound()">play sound</button>`.

`console.log` tells me, however:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': The provided value is not of type 'AudioBuffer'.`

what is going on?

Comment: Your own code shows that `playSound`takes a parameter - the AudioBuffer to play, yet your code for the click handler of the button doesn't pass any params to the function. I imagine the fix may be as simple as `<button onclick="playSound(songBuffer)">play sound</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing anything to your playSound function, which means that the line

```
source.buffer = buffer;
```

is interpreted as

```
source.buffer = undefined;
```

Since you have your songBuffer variable in a scope that is accessible to the playSound function, you can simply remove the buffer parameter and just do

```
source.buffer = songBuffer;
```

So, to wrap it up - keep it as it is, but edit the playSound function to look like this:

```
function playSound() {
 var source = context.createBufferSource(); 
 // creates a sound source
 source.buffer = songBuffer;                
 // tell the source which sound to play
 source.connect(context.destination);       
 // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)
 source.start(0);                           
 // play the source now                                          
}
```

Comment: Using above snippet, it still says `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`